# module custom payment doesnt show at checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, payment

I have Magento 2.4.3 with theme wolf and many stores and countries, well I tried to up a new module payment method (pagoEfectivo), I took the folder, put at `app/code`, I executed `bin/magento set:up, bin/magento s:s:d   bin/magento c:c  bin/magento c:f`, and when I stayed at checkout step, the payment method doesn't show (yes, I set values of the module at admin), but another payment methods are displayed without troubles. but if I tried to get up this module payment in new Magento (i tried Magento 2.4.5 p1 and Magento 2.4.3), the rest of the payment methods is showing without problems. logs are empty, the console doesn't load errors by this method of payment.

I debugged and found that the module is available but can't be used.

I am a newbie with Magento :/
**sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

According to whatever commands you have mentioned in the question, It shows missing the compile command. Can you try the below command & check?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile //I think you miss this command.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Finally, give proper file permission to var,pub & generated folder.

Comment: hi, well i executed these commands (s:d:c and indexer:reindex), i gave permission folders, remove and regenerated these folders.... but i didnt cant find any solutions to this trouble.... the final solutions would be make a custom payment module.... but i no idea how to conect to api of external service payment with magento... xd